Why does an individual random walk continue to behave randomly as time goes on?
Consider the two following random processes:

Process 1: Random walk starting at position $X_0 = 0$, we can write the position $X_n$ after $n$ steps as (where each $S_i$ is an independent random step with):

$$X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n S_i$$
$$P(S_i = +1) = p$$
$$P(S_i = -1) = 1-p = q$$


Process 2 (Polya-Urn): There is a hat with $m$ red balls and $n$ blue balls. Each time we select a ball, we put it back along with another ball of the same color. Here is a simulation for the ratio of colors in the hat:


Both of these processes can be shown to be martingale. As we can see, the average behavior of both systems stabilize towards the mean.
However, at the individual level : individual trajectories of the first process seem to "bounce around" a lot more whereas individual trajectories of the second process quickly stabilize and flatten out.
Mathematically, is there some way to understand why this is happening? Is this because the variance of a random walk continues to grow with time whereas the variance of the Polya Urn does not?
Can someone please help me understand why the individual trajectories on one of these plots stabilize but the individual trajectories on the other plot keep fluctuating?

R code for plot 1:
set.seed(123)

simulate_martingale <- function(n_steps, n_paths) {
    paths <- matrix(0, nrow = n_steps + 1, ncol = n_paths)
        for(j in 1:n_paths) {
        steps <- sample(c(-1, 1), n_steps, replace = TRUE)
        paths[2:(n_steps + 1), j] <- cumsum(steps)
    }
    
    return(paths)
}

n_steps <- 100  
n_paths <- 100 

paths <- simulate_martingale(n_steps, n_paths)

time <- 0:n_steps

plot(time, paths[,1], type = "l", 
     ylim = range(paths), 
     xlab = "Time", 
     ylab = "Value",
     main = "Simulation of a Martingale Process",
     col = "black")

for(i in 2:n_paths) {
    lines(time, paths[,i], col = "black")
}

mean_path <- rowMeans(paths)
lines(time, mean_path, col = "red", lwd = 2)

abline(h = 0, lty = 2)

R code for plot 2:
m <- 5          
n <- 2          
turns <- 1000   
trajectories <- 100 

simulate_polya_urn <- function(m, n, turns) {
    red_balls <- m
    blue_balls <- n
    ratios <- numeric(turns)
    
    for (t in 1:turns) {
        total_balls <- red_balls + blue_balls
        prob_red <- red_balls / total_balls
        draw <- sample(c(1, 0), size = 1, prob = c(prob_red, 1 - prob_red))
        
        if (draw == 1) {
            red_balls <- red_balls + 1
        } else {
            blue_balls <- blue_balls + 1
        }
        
        ratios[t] <- red_balls / (red_balls + blue_balls)
    }
    return(ratios)
}

all_trajectories <- matrix(0, nrow = turns, ncol = trajectories)

for (i in 1:trajectories) {
    all_trajectories[, i] <- simulate_polya_urn(m, n, turns)
}

theoretical_ratio <- m / (m + n)

plot(1:turns, all_trajectories[,1], type = "l", 
     ylim = c(0, 1),
     main = "Polya Urn Process: Individual Trajectories",
     xlab = "Draw Number",
     ylab = "Proportion of Red Balls",
     col = rgb(0.13, 0.44, 0.71, 0.1)) 

for(i in 2:trajectories) {
    lines(1:turns, all_trajectories[,i], col = rgb(0.13, 0.44, 0.71, 0.1))
}

abline(h = theoretical_ratio, col = "#cb181d", lty = 2, lwd = 2)


In the first example, you look at the total number of steps, while in the second case you look only at the ratio. If you plotted the ratio between steps forwards and steps backwards in the first plot you would see the same behaviour (w.r.t. variance) as in the second plot.

Is the second plot showing that some path exhibit 90%+ of red balls after 1000 draws? This looks very unlikely.

@ Matthew Spam: thank you! can you please elaborate on this?

@nicola Why would it be unlikely? We start with $5$ out of $7$ balls red.  There is a $\frac57 \cdot \frac68 \cdots \frac{17}{19}$ probability that the first $13$ draws are all red: that's better than $8%$, so around $8$ trajectories in the plot will do this. At that point, those trajectories are at $18$ out of $20$ red balls, and because the process is a martingale, they end up at an average of $90%$ red balls at the end, as well.

Is this because of the variance as well? i.e. the variance of polya urn is asymptotic but the variance of a random walk grows with time?

Both the proportion of one of the types of balls in Polya's urn and the simple symmetric random walk (i.e. $p=1/2$) are martingales. However, a fundamental difference between the two is that the former converges $P$-a.s., while the latter does not. Hence, in particular, what you see in a simulation of a proportion in Polya's urn is the eventual convergence to a (random) value - a realization of the random limit.
To see that the ratio between of one color of balls and the total number of balls in Polya's urn $(\Theta_n)_{n}$ converges almost surely, note that it is a martingale uniformly bounded between $0$ and $1$. The martingale convergence theorem tells us that $\Theta:=\lim_n\Theta_n$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$, $P$-a.s. On the other hand, a simple symmetric random walk $(X_n)_{n}$ diverges in a particular way: $P(\limsup_nX_n=\infty,\liminf_nX_n=-\infty)=1$, which tells us that the random walk will keep 'behaving randomly' indefinitely; this fact can be found in Durrett, Th. 4.1.2 and Ex. 4.1.1, p. 181.

thank you snoop! just a question: Is this because of the variance as well? i.e. the variance of polya urn is asymptotic but the variance of a random walk grows with time?

@konofoso take $Y_n=n+\varepsilon_n$ where $(\varepsilon_n)_n$ are IID with $P(\varepsilon_n=1)=P(\varepsilon_n=-1)=1/2$. Then the variance $V[Y_n]$ is constant, but $Y_n$ diverges to $\infty$ a.s.
